# Change cell value in database. Yii2

Tags: database, activerecord, yii2, sql-update

I wanna change cell value by += and then update it. But Program add this values and create a new row, and i need just add to current.

`

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 100, ',')) !== false) {
                        $wareHouse = Warehouse::find()->all();
                        $products = Products::find()->all();
                        $createBoth = true;
                      foreach ($wareHouse as $wr)
                      {
                          foreach ($products as $prod)
                          {
                              if ($prod->product_name==$row[0]&&$prod->warehouse_id==$wr->id&&$wr->warehouse_name==$row[2]){
                                  $prod->qty+=$row[1];
                                  $prod->update();
                                  $createBoth=false;
                              }
                          }
                      }
```

`

Comment: the update function don't create rows ...    check better  . if you have some other code that insert code  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this;

```
    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 100, ',')) !== false) {
        $wareHouse = Warehouse::find()->all(); 
        $createBoth = true;
        foreach ($wareHouse as $wr) {
            if ($wr->warehouse_name == $row[2]):
                $prod = Products::find(['product_name' => $row[0], 'warehouse_id' => $wr->id])->one();
                $prod->qty = $prod->qty + $row[1];
                $prod->update();
                $createBoth = false;
            endif;
        }
    }
```